Book about a post-apocalyptic Messenger Service that is seeking to use the last shuttle to activate a satellite system for communications
A science fiction book about a post-apocalyptic horse riding Messenger Service whose leader is seeking to use the last space shuttle to get to a space station to reactivate a satellite system to reconnect the world.

In roughly which year did you read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

"Book about a post-apocalyptic messenger service" must be The Postman "something something last shuttle" or not then.

It was in the 80s as I recall. But I'm 65 so that's not a rock solid memory. And it's definitely not "the postman"...
